# Failing to recognize fetch_assoc method

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to upload an excel file to my site and save the data in my database, however i'm failing to do so and getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc() ... But i'm not sure how to handle it, and i haven't found a question related on SO, any help?

```
function getSchedule($filepath,$con,$filename){

    require_once 'excel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath); 
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
        $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
        $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

        list($location, $date) = explode('-', $filename, 2);
        $LastChange = date('d/m/Y h:i:s');
        $Status='Open';

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Js";
$dbname = "jr";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Schedule";
$conn->query($sql);


    // output data of each row
    while($row = $conn->fetch_assoc()) {


         $sql1="DELETE FROM `schedule` WHERE " . $row["Date"]. "='$date'";   
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

    }

$conn->close();


        for ($row = 3; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO `schedule` (`Status`,`LastChange`, `Location`,`Date`,`AFNumber`,`Name`,`01-IN`, `01-OUT`, `02-IN`, `02-OUT`, `03-IN`, `03-OUT`, `04-IN`, `04-OUT`, `05-IN`, `05-OUT`, `06-IN`, `06-OUT`, `07-IN`, `07-OUT`, `08-IN`, `08-OUT`, `09-IN`, `09-OUT`, `10-IN`, `10-OUT`, `11-IN`, `11-OUT`, `12-IN`, `12-OUT`, `13-IN`, `13-OUT`, `14-IN`, `14-OUT`, `15-IN`, `15-OUT`, `16-IN`, `16-OUT`, `17-IN`, `17-OUT`, `18-IN`, `18-OUT`, `19-IN`, `19-OUT`, `20-IN`, `20-OUT`, `21-IN`, `21-OUT`, `22-IN`, `22-OUT`, `23-IN`, `23-OUT`, `24-IN`, `24-OUT`, `25-IN`, `25-OUT`, `26-IN`, `26-OUT`, `27-IN`, `27-OUT`, `28-IN`, `28-OUT`, `29-IN`, `29-OUT`, `30-IN`, `30-OUT`, `31-IN`, `31-OUT`)  VALUES ('".$Status."', '".$LastChange."','".$location."','".$date."',";
            for ($col = 0; $col < ($highestColumnIndex -1); ++ $col) {
                $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                if($col==($highestColumnIndex -2)){
                     $sql.="'$val'";
                }else{
                    $sql.="'$val', ";}
            }
            echo "Index:".$highestColumnIndex."<br>";
            if($highestColumnIndex < 63){
                $temp = 63 - $highestColumnIndex;
                for($i = 1;$i <= $temp; $i++){
                    if($i == $temp){
                        $sql.=",''";
                    } else{
                    $sql.=", '',";
                    }
                }
            }
            $sql .=")";
            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            } else {
                echo "<br><br>Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }
        }//End For Each Row
    }//End For Each Worksheet
}//End getHours Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

> array mysqli_result::fetch_assoc ( void )

This means that you should provide it with a result of a query, not a connection. Change your code to this and it should work

```
$results = $conn->query($sql); //assign query to a variable and get mysqli_result in return

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { //use that in the while loop
```

Comment: i'm getting now Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Comment: @dan That means that your query has an error an instead of mysqli_result it returns FALSE. Do `var_dump($conn -> error);` after `$result = $conn->query($sql);` to see what is wrong with it

Comment: i'm getting string(0) ""     what does this mean?

Comment: try to do `print_r($result)`

Comment: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 69 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 220 [type] => 0 )

Comment: Ok, found the error. Didn't notice you have $result inside while loop. Change `$result = $conn->query($sql);  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` to `$results = $conn->query($sql);  while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: The thing was that you have a variable `$result` that gets assigned a mysqli_result object. You run a while loop and inside it you override the variable with a DELETE query that returns boolean and ruins everything

Comment: well man the upload worked, yet the Delete query isn't executing..I'm not gonna ask you about it..but any directions on it? i checked the variables in the query and its holding the correct values

Comment: not sure if that is going to do anything but try changing it to `$result = $conn -> query($sql1); var_dump($sql1); var_dump($result);` and see what it gives you back.

Comment: i got several rows the same: string(46) "DELETE FROM `schedule` WHERE 07-2015='07-2015'" bool(true) string(46) "DELETE FROM `schedule` WHERE 07-2015='07-2015'" bool(true) string(46) "DELETE FROM `schedule` WHERE 07-2015='07-2015'" bool(true)

Comment: Just to make sure, you have a table schedule with a column 07-2015 and some rows have values of 07-2015. Is that right?

Comment: yeah..Dear i got it to work, i removed the single quotes on $date

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the connection object `$conn`.Use

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Schedule";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```